# Pidof not finding the process

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find out a shell script process ID using pidof or ps command or any.

All i want is only the process id of it. I have used 'pidof -x test.sh'. Which is not working. Note: I don't want to invoke the /bin/sh or /bin/bash - because the script will not work. If i invoke /bin/sh in script, pidof is working.

Please help

Comment: Your question can't be understood in its current form. Try to enhance it, add an example etc..

Comment: i need to find out the process of a particular script - let us say i have 1sleep.sh and 2sleep.sh and tailf sleep.out running in the processes list. I want to find out the process of 2sleep.sh only

Comment: Ok, got it. (You should have added that to your question, maybe it would get upvoted then)... As you stated, when the scripts get called like `bash script.sh` then `pgrep -f "bash/script.sh"` is the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pgrep -f script is giving the expected result.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another caveat even for non-script processes:

`pidof` ignores:

- zombie processes
- processes in disk sleep

So pidof as well as killall (same codebase) unlike pgrep won't not see your process as long as it is blocked in disk i/o.

I just experienced this with pidof - found, not found, found, ...

Comment: The second point was the case for me. I wanted to send a (non-kill) signal to a backup program but it was in an "uninterruptible sleep" state (shown in `ps` output as the `D` flag), which means it was doing some important IO. After a short while it came out of the state and `pidof` found it again. Guess I'll just change my alias to use `pgrep` instead. :>

Comment: Second point for me as well; `find` in D state not being found by `pidof`. Oddly `top` is only showing it when it's in D state and not at other times.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep your_search_string | awk {printf $2}
```

Comment: Then you must adjust your filter message

Answer (score 0):

both pidof and pgrep are options to find the pid for a certain process. do not run `ps -ef | grep "your_command"` because you have now polluted your result with the grep match too.

- use `pidof -s [program]` to find the parent process id.
- use `pidof [program]` to find ALL pids (ie. python is running multiple times on your system).
- use `pgrep [program]` to match the name of your binary that is run by python (because pidof is not well suited for this use-case).

[Fox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/175857/fox) explained the difference between pidof vs pgrep quite well. see his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351775/252947)

I'll copy it here for convenience:

> The programs pgrep and pidof are not quite the same thing, but they
> are very similar. For example:
>
> ```
> $ pidof 'firefox'
> 5696
> $ pgrep '[i]ref'
> 5696
> $ pidof '[i]ref'
> $ printf '%s\n' "$?"
> 1
> ```
>
> As you can see, pidof failed to find a match for [i]ref. This is
> because pidof program returns a list of all process IDs associated
> with a program called program. On the other hand, pgrep re returns a
> list of all process IDs associated with a program whose name matches
> the regular expression re.
>
> In their most basic forms, the equivalence is actually:
>
> ```
> $ pidof 'program'
> $ pgrep '^program$'
> ```
>
> As yet another concrete example, consider:
>
> ```
> $ ps ax | grep '[w]atch'
>    12 ?        S      0:04 [watchdog/0]
>    15 ?        S      0:04 [watchdog/1]
>    33 ?        S<     0:00 [watchdogd]
> 18451 pts/5    S+     0:02 watch -n600 tail log-file
> $ pgrep watch
> 12
> 15
> 33
> 18451
> $ pidof watch
> 18451
> ```

Comment: A delicious trick: `ps -ef | grep "your_comman[d\]"` This alters the grep command line to not match itself (contains the pre-processed regex with degenerate character class) while still matching the command (using the post-processed regex). The degenerate character class can be added to any character in the command name, I usually apply it to the last character because I never remember the trick until half-way through typing out the grep command.